# Duplex outlet always ‘hot’

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I am replacing duplex outlets in my home and have successfully regained power with the outlet but the outlet is no longer controlled by the light switch.
Old outlet
[image: old outlet]

Wiring configuration in the old outlet
[image: Wiring configuration in the old outlet]

New outlet

[image: new outlet with where I wired]

I have removed the tab that connected the hot side (brass screws).
[image]

Thank you for any help as to why the red wire isn’t responding to the switch would be wonderful, thank you!

Comment: is the switch working correctly?

Comment: In the picture labelled 'old outlet' it looks like both tabs are connected. This would mean it was either always only controlled by the switch, or always only unswitched, like any regular outlet. It looks like the old switch had only one source of power, not two; one of the wires p, either the red or the black was dead. Connecting a red and a black wire to the same yoke without breaking off the tab was cause an instant trip in the breaker.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you so much for your feedback, I was able to follow most of your comment.  I did have a photo of the before wiring configuration in the old outlet (luckily I took a photo!) and added it to this feed.

Jsotola, I can only assume that the switch works correctly because it controlled the bottom outlet of the receptacle prior to me changing it out.

Comment: @chris Taylor, if fed from the same circuit the breaker won't trip if the tab is not broken. It sounds like the op did it correct so a failed switch is the best thing to check.

Comment: In the first photo of the old outlet, it looks like both tabs are connected.  In the second photo, with wires attached, it looks like the tab is missing on the hot side.  Is the first a pic of the actual outlet? Or just another one you had laying around of the same model?

Comment: Just to clarify:  Did you break off the tab on the white side?

Comment: Chris, the original outlet photo is an extra.  I couldn't get the prongs to release the wires, so I had to totally disassemble the outlet-in-question.  I realize the confusion the first photo might have caused *sorry!* I added that because I thought I might have inserted my wires in the incorrect slots on the new unit (since there were twice as many backwire holes).

Comment: Not an answer but a picture of a diagram, and this is the only place I can post it; I can't be posted in the Comments section. I hope this helps. [![How To Wire A Split-Circuit Outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INeBD.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INeBD.jpg)